# Creating a copy of the cairo_t

Tags: cairo

Looking quickly, I cannot find a trivial way to copy a `cairo_t` including the entire stack of saved graphics states.

Is there one?

This is needed because a certain API that I need to provide an implementation for requires this mechanic: copying a stack of saved graphics states.

Alternatively, is it possible to "peek" at a state below the tip of the `cairo_t` stack when using getter functions?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but nope, there is no way for either of those.